# a question which seem related to derivation of argument princple

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

This question is from ponnusamy and silvermann Complex variables ( Subsection : Argument Principle)and I am unable to solve it.

> Question: Let f(z) be analytic inside and on a simple closed contour except for a finite number of poles inside C. Denote the zeroes by $z_1, z_2,...,z_k$ ( none of which lies on C)and the poles by $w_1, w_2,...,w_m$. If g(z) is analytic inside and on C, prove that

$\frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_C g(z) \frac{f'(z) }{f(z)} dz = \sum_{j=1}^n g(z_j) -\sum_{j=1}^m g(w_j)$,

Attempt : I assumed $f(z)= \frac{(z-z_1)^{k_1} ... (z-z_n)^{k_n} F(z)}{(z-w_1)^{l_1} ...(z-w_m)^{l_m}}$, where F(Z) is analytic in and on C.
and then I Took Logarithm and then 1st order derivative both sides and then multiplying by g(z) and then using cauchy's formula I got LHS equal to $1/ 2\pi i \int_{C} g(z) \frac{ f'(z)}{f(z)} dz$ and RHS equal to and RHS equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n k_i g(z_i) -\sum_{j=1}^{m} l_j g(z_j)$ so, I am getting an extra $k_i $ and $l_j$ in each sum.

For more clarity I am adding 2nd last step which is $1/2\pi i \int_{C} \frac{g(z) f'(z)} {f(z)}dz =$1/2\pi i$[\sum_{i=1}^n k_i \int_{C} \frac{g(z)}{z-z_i} dz -\sum_{j=1}^m l_j \frac{g(z}{z-w_j}dz+ \int_{C} \frac{F'(z)}{F(z)} g(z)dz]$.

Can you please tell what mistake I made in 2nd last step so that I got an extra factor of $k_i$ and $l_j$ in each of th e terms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mistake. If $z_j$ and $w_j$ are the *distinct* zeros and poles of $f$ with respective multiplicities $k_j$ and $l_j$ then
$$
\frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_C g(z) \frac{f'(z) }{f(z)} dz = \sum_j k_j g(z_j) -\sum_j  l_j g(w_j) \, .
$$

Another convention is to list multiple zeros/poles multiple times, according to their multiplicity, and then
$$
\frac {1}{2\pi i} \int_C g(z) \frac{f'(z) }{f(z)} dz = \sum_j g(z_j) -\sum_j  g(w_j)
$$
because for a $k_j$-fold zero at $z_j$ the term $g(z_j)$ occurs $k_j$ times in the sum (and similarly for the poles).